# Agastya's Palm Leaf Astrology

Tags: scripture, astrology, agastya

Many Palm leaf Astrology centers exist in south India. It is said that Agastya has written astrological predictions in palm leaf. If that is so only one set of palm leaf should exist. But so many are there at present. Is ther any evidence in Hindu scriptures or mythology about this palm leaf astrology?